# Объединение двух массивов в C# (заданное количество элементов)

Tags: c#, массивы, linq

Есть два массива list1 и list2. При помощи LINQ нужно получить массив list3 состоящий из заданного кол. элементов из list1 и заданного кол. элементов из list2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функциями:

- [Concat()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), которая объединяет две последовательности в одну.
- [Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), которая позволяет вернуть первые N элементов из последовательности

Например

```
    var list1 = new List<string>()
    {
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
    };

    var list2 = new List<string>()
    {
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
    };

    var list3 = list1.Take(5).Concat(list2.Take(3));
```

В итоге `list3` будет содержать 5 элементов из первого списка, и 3 - из второго

```
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3"
```

Если вы хотите из списков брать не первые элементы, а 'элементы где-нибудь из середины списка, то тогда вам в помощь функция [Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx), которая позволяет пропустить N количество элементов с начала последовательности

```
var list3 = list1.Skip(2).Take(5).Concat(list2.Take(3));
```

Результат в `list3`

```
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", "2", "3"
```