# Слияние двух массивов в один массив - C#

Tags: c#, массивы, динамические-массивы

У меня есть два массива:

```
string[] counts = { "Count 1", "Count 2", "Count 3", "Count 4" }
string[] controls = { "comboBox_username", "textBox_password" }
```

Мне нужно их сместить друг с другом, чтобы в итоге получилось:

```
string[] query = { "Count 1 = comboBox_username", "Count 2 = textBox_password", "Count 3", "Count 4" }
```

Поясню немного.
Я хочу создать метод для выполнения Sql команды через метод с аргументами. У меня есть метод:

```
public static void Compare(Form @this, string table, string[] @counts, string[] @control)
{
    //Объединение двух массивов
    //text1 должен выглядеть таким образом string text1 = "Count1 = comboBox.Text.Trim() AND Count2 = textBox.Tex.Trim()";
    string query = "SELECT " + string.Join(", ", @counts) + " FROM " + table + " WHERE " + text1 + ""; //Строка запроса
    // Команда запроса
}
```

Инициализация метода: 
Command это класс, где находится метод.

```
Command.Compare(Controls.Owner.FindForm(), "Name table", new string[] { "Count 1", "Count 2", "Count 3", "Count 4" }, new string[] { "comboBox_username", "textBox_password" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш подход чреват SQL injection, поскольку вы отправляете прямиком в бд данные, введённые пользователем. Никогда, запомните, никогда нельзя доверять данным, введённым пользователем
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используйте ORM для работы с базой данных вместо прямых запросов.

Как сливать массивы, уже [объяснено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512420/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) на этом же сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Если подходить к вашей задаче формально, то подойдёт что-то такое:

```
var result = counts.Zip(controls, (l, r) => $"{l} = {r}")
                   .Concat(counts.Skip(controls.Length))
                   .Concat(controls.Skip(counts.Length));
```

Но в реальности, как говорится более подробно в соседнем ответе, конкатенировать строку ввода пользователя в SQL-запрос — **очень плохая идея**. Стоит юзеру ввести в `textBox_password` значение наподобие `xxx OR 1 = 1`, и подойдёт любой пароль.